# Android Style themes

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building an App, and I want to build an app with custom UI elements (like the ones in Dropbox/Instagram). I do not want to build using the native elements.

I saw that Android allows you to [theme](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) your elements. Now what I am looking for is a 'Twitter Bootstrap' like themes for Android. Tried searching, couldn't find. Any help?